# Seeking clean resolution for zombie who caused by git fetch / ubuntu motd

Tags: ubuntu, git, jenkins, zombie

I have jenkins and gitosis running on the same [Ubuntu 10.04] server. Jenkins fetches git commits from a repo served by gitosis (also running on the same server). Many repos, actually, since there are many jobs in Jenkins. Every now and then I end up with a zombie `who` process, where the root cause appears to be some Ubuntu-specific scripts to update /etc/motd. Here's what (part of) the process table looked like earlier today:

```
jenkins  30042     1  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 git fetch -t gitosis@example.com:testRepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
jenkins  30060 30042  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 ssh gitosis@example.com git-upload-pack 'testRepo.git'
root     30066   703  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 sshd: gitosis [priv]
root     30096 30066  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 sh -c /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /bin/run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d > /var/run/motd.new
root     30097 30096  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 /bin/run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
root     30129 30097  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo
root     30148 30129  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo
root     30451 30148  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 [who] <defunct>
```

To clear it up I basically just killed every parent of the zombie `who`, then the zombie disappeared.

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening or gracefully deal with it when it does?

Is there some way to disable these motd scripts *sometimes*? Like, only when Jenkins is doing `git fetch`? Actually, what would be perfect is if I could somehow disable the motd scripts whenever the gitosis user tries to SSH in (e.g. whenever any git client/server interaction takes place).

Maybe there's a straightforward way with Bash to kill any git process left running for over an hour? Ugh.

I generally *like* the handy motd provided by these scripts so I don't want to completely disable them. Sure would be nice if they'd timeout on their own. Why the heck is the motd updated on every login? Once a day seems like plenty.

I don't really want to switch to gitolite or a different git server, gitosis otherwise works fine. I don't want to switch to another protocol besides SSH; gitosis relies on SSH. Since gitosis is running on the same server, I *should* be able to refer to the git repositories using `file:///` syntax. I'll give that a shot now. Update... nope, that won't work since that bypasses gitolite and won't allow jenkins to push tags back upstream. I could give jenkins more ACLs, but I'd rather stick with gitolite.

Side note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758703/forcing-a-timeout-in-git-push-pull) won't help since it appears the problem occurs *after* the SSH connection is established.

Comment: Clean resolution for zombie? Headshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If I'm reading this right, and I like to think that I am..*

Then you're asking for a very roundabout way to disable `update-motd` on ubuntu.

Have a look in `/etc/cron.d` for `/etc/cron.d/update-motd`, and if you've got it, mv it to /tmp.  That should stop it.

I don't think you should kill long-running processes.  I do think that no harm can come out of disabling `update-motd` though.

You might want to have a look inside `/etc/update-motd.d`

> /usr/sbin/update-motd uses run-parts to execute each script in
>   /etc/update-motd.d in lexigraphic order, concatenating the results
>   with the message-of-the-day header, /etc/motd.tail.
>
> In this way, users, or even other packages can drop scripts into
>   /etc/update-motd.d to affect the MOTD.
>   (Lifted from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd)

[Here's a blogpost](http://deadmemes.net/2010/10/19/fear-and-loathing-in-debianubuntu-or-who-needs-etcmotd/) from someone else who hates update-motd as much as you ;)

Comment: Pretty much, but I think I found the way to only *sometimes* get information provided by the motd scripts: (1) disable everything in `/etc/update-motd.d` like you say, then (2) add specific bits to my `~/.bash_login` such as `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo` and `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check`.

Comment: I never read them anyway.  I don't see the point in my login shell telling me shit i'm not interested in anyway.  If I wanna know the load, i use `top`